# How to assert element property value with Espresso-web?

Tags: javascript, android, webdriver, android-espresso, android-espresso-web

I'm working on a subclass of default Android WebView with some additional functionality (content-filtering) on the top. So i override [`shouldInterceptRequest(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) and prevent loading of some resource (let's say images with filename "image.png").

Now i want to test this functionality with the help of [Espresso-Web](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web). So i do start embedded http server (with WireMock) and load some webpage that uses that "image.png" and it's expected to be blocked.

How can i assert the state of DOM element with id "someId"?

I expected to have smth like:

```
    onWebView().
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, blockImageId)) // finds the DOM node
        .check(webMatches(getProperty("naturalWidth"), equalTo("0"))) // "getProperty"?
```

**What i need is smth like "getProperty()" that just generates JS to access the property of node found by `findElement(Locator.ID, blockImageId)`, is there anything out-of-box?**

I was able to find `getText()` but it seems it does it in completely different way (so i can't just request another "node property"):

```
/** Returns the visible text beneath a given DOM element. */
  public static Atom<String> getText() {
    return new GetTextTransformingAtom(new GetVisibleTextSimpleAtom(), castOrDie(String.class));
  }
```

I was able to do it in JS way:

```
      // JS-way helpers
    
      const val naturalWidth = "naturalWidth"
      const val notBlockedImageWidth = 50
      const val blockedImageWidth = 0

      fun getPropertyForElementId(elementId: String, property: String): Atom<String> =
          Atoms.script(
              """return String(document.getElementById("$elementId").$property);""",
              Atoms.castOrDie(String::class.java))

      fun imageIsBlocked(elementId: String): WebAssertion<String>? = WebViewAssertions.webMatches(
          getPropertyForElementId(elementId, naturalWidth),
          equalTo(blockedImageWidth.toString())) {
          """An image with id="$elementId" IS expected to be blocked, but it's NOT."""
      }

      // part of the test

      val redImage = "image.png"
      load(
            listOf(blockingPathPrefix),
            """
            |<html>
            |<body>
            |  <img id="$blockImageId" src="${blockingPathPrefix}$redImage"/>
            |  <img id="$notBlockImageId" src="$greenImage"/>
            |</body>
            |</html>
            |""".trimMargin()
        )

        onWebView()
            .withTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  // it's already loaded
            .check(imageIsBlocked(blockImageId))       // red image IS blocked
            .check(imageIsNotBlocked(notBlockImageId)) // green image is NOT blocked
```

I do understand that the way i did it is suboptimal as it joins everything: searching of the node and accessing at once and i wonder what's the right way to do it. Any suggestions, links?

PS. "naturalWidth" is just a property that helps me in this particular case. In common case i just need to access a property of found DOM node and it can be some other property next time (eg "style.display" to check element visibility).

PS. Can anybody explain how to write `WebDriverAtomScripts`, eg. smth similar to [`WebDriverAtomScripts.GET_VISIBLE_TEXT_ANDROID`](https://github.com/bootstraponline/platform_frameworks_testing/blob/3536a8e34cdc8f93c22d97e5c9fa4be654a83191/espresso/web/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/web/webdriver/WebDriverAtomScripts.java#L5506)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anything out-of-box?

The answer to your question is "no", I don't think there is anything better out-of-the-box than creating an `Atom` like you are doing (or similar approaches like `Atoms.scriptWithArgs` or subclassing `SimpleAtom`).

Your best bet is to file a feature request here (and then maybe propose/contribute an implementation): https://github.com/android/android-test

You can assert on the html document with xpath, but that won't work for computed DOM node attributes like you are looking for.

```java
onWebView()
.check(webContent(hasElementWithXpath("//*[@id=\"myButton\" and @type=\"button\"]")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This might help in this particular case to check whether a node exists. However i'm afraid i still need some access to node properties (to assert it's visibility for example). Any idea on how to write this tiny JS part to extract a property value given node found with `findElement (..)` ?